# SPRING CSRF throws 405 despite CSRF token in request

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, csrf

I have a web application that works when I put `<security:csrf disabled="true"/>` in my security config, but doesn't work when I enable it. I conclude therefore than I'm an idiot, but can't figure out why.

The symptoms are:

- Throws 405 when deployed in Tomcat with `<security:csrf/>`
- Works in Tomcat with `<security:csrf disabled="true"/>`
- Works when run under STS's Pivotal server, even with `<security:csrf/>`

The precise error is:

```
"POST /works-1.0-SNAPSHOT/auth/register HTTP/1.1" 405 1088
```

Here is my registration form:

```
<%@ page import="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Register</h1>
        <div class="error">${error}</div>
        <c:url var="post_url" value="/auth/register"/>
        <form action="${post_url}" method="post" >
      <p>
        <label for="j_username">Login:</label>
        <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" value="${j_username}"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="j_displayname">Name:</label>
        <input id="j_displayname" name="j_displayname" type="text" value="${j_displayname}"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="j_password">Password:</label>
        <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" />
      </p>
       <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                        value="${_csrf.token}" />
      <input  type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <a href="/auth/login">Login</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

(If you think that this form looks suspiciously like [SDN4-cineasts](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-cineasts)'s one, you're right: my project is derived from that source code.)

As you can see, the CSRF token is in there. When I "show source" on the displayed web page, I can see that the token is indeed present.  Any ideas?

Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.artdecode.works</groupId>
    <artifactId>works</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Works database</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version> -->
        <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.commons.version>1.12.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.commons.version>
        <!-- <spring.security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version> -->
        <spring.security.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <!-- <neo4j.version>2.3.2</neo4j.version>  -->
        <neo4j.version>3.0.3</neo4j.version>
        <!-- <sdn.version>4.1.0.M1</sdn.version> -->
        <sdn.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</sdn.version>
        <neo4j.ogm.version>2.0.4</neo4j.ogm.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- J2EE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


       <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${sdn.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Neo4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!-- Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-test</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.ogm.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${sdn.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>neo4j</id>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.6.5.v20120716</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                    <jvmArgs></jvmArgs>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>username</name>
                            <value>neo4j</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>password</name>
                            <value>neo</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
      <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Here is my security configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled">
    </security:global-method-security>

    <security:http> <!-- use-expressions="true" -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/import/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/register" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAnonymous() || hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/auth/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/auth/login?login_error=true"
            default-target-url="/user"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/auth/denied" />
        <security:csrf/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userRepository">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5">
                <security:salt-source system-wide="cewuiqwzie"/>
            </security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Comment: why are you saying there is an issue with the csrf ? 405 means "method not allowed", which may rather mean that you doesn't have a request mapping for "/works-1.0-SNAPSHOT/auth/register" and POST action ?

Comment: I say that because the issue goes away when I disable CSRF protection. If I disable CSRF protection, I can see /.../auth/register, so there must be a valid request mapping.

Comment: Could it be that there is an incompatibility between Spring and the JRE? Are there any constraints on the maximum JRE version I can use with any given Spring version? I'm using 1.8 currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: I had cookies disabled in my browser. It was not a problem with either Tomcat or my code, it was a problem with my browser.

Could someone at Spring please make it possible to distinguish between "Invalid CSRF token found" and "Expected token is empty (probably cookie not set)"?